# Python3 os.kill() is failing inside gitlab runner using windows dockers

Tags: python, windows, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have following setup:

- windows 10 professional, running dockers-desktop (with `"exec-opts": ["isolation=process"]` - due msys issues)
- docker image that is built to contain msys2 - with python3 (Python 3.9.6) installed via pacman
- gitlab runner with configuration set to `executor = "docker-windows"` and `shell = "powershell"`

And the following (simplified real case) script fails:

```
import signal
import subprocess
print("HELLO")

proc = subprocess.Popen(('python3','-c','import time;time.sleep(3);print("PROCESS EXIT")'),
                           creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)

print("PROCESS LAUNCH")
proc.send_signal( signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT )
ret = proc.wait(5)
print("PROC EXIT: %s"%ret )
```

With output:

```
$ python3 silly.py
HELLO
PROCESS LAUNCH
OSError: [WinError 1] Incorrect function
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\builds\XXX\silly.py", line 9, in <module>
    proc.send_signal( signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT )
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\subprocess.py", line 1543, in send_signal
    os.kill(self.pid, signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT)
SystemError: <built-in function kill> returned a result with an error set
```

If i ran the docker image (`docker run -it --rm -v C:\TMP:C:\build/ test_image`) and launch the job manually, the script works fine:

```
PS C:\build> python3 silly.py
HELLO
PROCESS LAUNCH
PROC EXIT: 3221225794
PS C:\build>
```

The output is after invoking powershell (`C:\>powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass`), but the script works also with default cmd that comes with docker started.

Any ideas what is causing the simple script to fail *inside* the gitlab runner (but not outside?).

Comment: Consider changing the title of your question so that it can be useful to other people in the future too

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the exact reason, but I was running into a similar problem using testing.postgresql which sends a signal in the same fashion when you tell the server to stop.

One workaround you can use if you don't care about graceful shutdown is instead of doing proc.send_signal() you can do proc.kill() which will forcefully terminate the process and for me didn't cause any issues. Again, note that this is basically equivalent to calling TASKKILL /F /IM [process name] from the command line, which forcefully closes the process and doesn't give it a chance to do any cleanup. If you need cleanup, make sure you do it manually if you are going to be calling kill().

Comment: TY for the comment - i actually ended up doing workaround in they way that the subprocess (that i had in this case source-code control) dies when the STDIN gets closed -- and closing STDIN works fine (also inside the docker env)